# How to draw a point in 3d coordinates on C# WinForms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, gdi+

I want to have points drawn in runtime in a WinForms application. How do I do that?

Answer (score 7):

### The simple answer

You need to implement some kind of projective transformation to convert  each `Vector3` from (X,Y,Z) coordinates to `PointF` with (X,Y) coordinates.

On each `Paint` event, move the origin to the center of the drawing surface and project the 3D points with some math as follows

```
g.TranslateTransform(ClientSize.Width/2, ClientSize.Height/2);
pixel.X = scale * vector.X / (camera.Z -vector.Z);
pixel.Y = -scale * vector.Y / (camera.Z -vector.Z);
g.DrawEllipse(Pens.Black, pixel.X-2, pixel.Y-2, 4,4);
```

Where `g` is the `Graphics` object passed from the `Paint` event. The reason for the negative for the `Y` coordinate is because in WinForms positive `Y` is downwards, and for 3D graphics it makes sense to objey the right hand rules and have `Y` pointing upwards. The `DrawEllipse` method draws a little circle where the point is. Use `FillEllipse` to fill in the circle instead if you want.

---

### The detailed answer

I have a [sample project on GitHub](https://github.com/ja72/WindowsFormsRender3D) on simple rendering of 3D geometry in Winforms.

[image: fig1]

There are other parts to the sample you can ignore, but I will explain the process I came up to render simple 3D objects on a WinForms control.

1. **`PictureBox`** is where the target control for the rendering. This is the only requirement for the form. To have Control placed for things to show on. `PictureBox` is convenient, and it supports double buffering on the get-go.
2. **`Camera`** is a class that does the rendering. It is responsible for the following tasks.

   - Reference to the target control and handling the `Paint` event.
   - Handling the math for projecting 3D points into pixels.
   - Checks if an object is visible (backface culling).
   - Configure the `Graphics` object before rendering on screen.
   - Handling any mouse events if needed.
   - Define the 3D viewpoint properties.

   A simplified version of my `Camera` class is below. The things to look into is the `Project()` methods that take up geometry `Vector3` objects and return `PointF` objects.

   ```
   using static SingleConstants;

   public delegate void CameraPaintHandler(Camera camera, Graphics g);

   public class Camera
   {
       public event CameraPaintHandler Paint;

       /// <summary>
       /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="Camera" /> class.
       /// </summary>
       /// <param name="control">The target control to draw scene.</param>
       /// <param name="fov">
       /// The FOV angle (make zero for orthographic projection).
       /// </param>
       /// <param name="sceneSize">Size of the scene across/</param>
       public Camera(string name, Control control, float fov, float sceneSize = 1f)
       {
           Name = name;
           OnControl = control;
           FOV = fov;
           SceneSize = sceneSize;
           LightPos = new Vector3(0 * sceneSize, 0 * sceneSize / 2, -sceneSize);
           Orientation = Quaternion.Identity;
           Target = Vector3.Zero;
           control.Paint += (s, ev) =>
           {
               Paint?.Invoke(this, ev.Graphics);
           };
       }

       public GraphicsState SetupView(Graphics g, SmoothingMode smoothing = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias)
       {
           var gs = g.Save();
           g.SmoothingMode = smoothing;
           var center = ViewCenter;
           g.TranslateTransform(center.X, center.Y);
           return gs;
       }
       public Point ViewCenter => new Point(
           OnControl.Margin.Left + OnControl.ClientSize.Width/2,
           OnControl.Margin.Top + OnControl.ClientSize.Height/2);
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public Control OnControl { get; }
       public float SceneSize { get; set; }
       public float FOV { get; set; }
       public Quaternion Orientation { get; set; }
       public Vector3 LightPos { get; set; }
       public Vector3 Target { get; set; }
       public int ViewSize
       {
           get => Math.Min(
           OnControl.ClientSize.Width - OnControl.Margin.Left - OnControl.Margin.Right,
           OnControl.ClientSize.Height - OnControl.Margin.Top - OnControl.Margin.Bottom);
       }
       public int ViewHalfSize => ViewSize/2;
       public float Scale => ViewHalfSize/SceneSize;
       public float DrawSize
       {
           get => 2 * (float)Math.Tan(FOV / 2 * Math.PI / 180);
           set
           {
               FOV = 360/pi*Atan(value/2);
           }
       }
       /// <summary>
       /// Get the pixels per model unit scale.
       /// </summary>
       public Vector3 EyePos { get => Target + Vector3.Transform(Vector3.UnitZ * SceneSize / DrawSize, Quaternion.Inverse(Orientation)); }
       public float EyeDistance
       {
           get => SceneSize/DrawSize;
           set
           {
               DrawSize = SceneSize/value;
           }
       }
       public Vector3 RightDir { get => Vector3.TransformNormal(Vector3.UnitX, Matrix4x4.CreateFromQuaternion(Quaternion.Inverse(Orientation))); }
       public Vector3 UpDir { get => Vector3.TransformNormal(Vector3.UnitY, Matrix4x4.CreateFromQuaternion(Quaternion.Inverse(Orientation))); }
       public Vector3 EyeDir { get => Vector3.TransformNormal(Vector3.UnitZ, Matrix4x4.CreateFromQuaternion(Quaternion.Inverse(Orientation))); }

       public PointF Project(Vector3 node)
       {
           float r = 2 * (float)Math.Tan(FOV / 2 * Math.PI / 180);
           int sz = ViewHalfSize;
           float f = sz/r;
           float camDist = SceneSize / r;
           var R = Matrix4x4.CreateFromQuaternion(Orientation);
           return Project(node, f, camDist, R);
       }

       protected PointF Project(Vector3 node, float f, float camDist, Matrix4x4 R)
       {
           var point = Vector3.Transform(node-Target, R);
           return new PointF(
               +f  * point.X / (camDist - point.Z),
               -f  * point.Y / (camDist - point.Z));
       }

       public RectangleF Project(Bounds bounds)
       {
           var nodes = bounds.GetNodes();
           var points = Project(nodes);
           if (points.Length>0) {

               RectangleF box = new RectangleF(points[0], SizeF.Empty);
               for (int i = 1; i < points.Length; i++)
               {
                   box.X = Math.Min(box.X, points[i].X);
                   box.Y = Math.Min(box.Y, points[i].Y);
                   box.Width = Math.Max(box.Width, points[i].X-box.X);
                   box.Height = Math.Max(box.Height, points[i].Y-box.Y);
               }
               return box;
           }
           return RectangleF.Empty;
       }

       public PointF[] Project(Triangle triangle) => Project(new[] { triangle.A, triangle.B, triangle.C });
       public PointF[] Project(Polygon polygon) => Project(polygon.Nodes);
       /// <summary>
       /// Projects the specified nodes into a 2D canvas by applied the camera 
       /// orientation and projection.
       /// </summary>
       /// <param name="nodes">The nodes to project.</param>
       /// <returns>A list of Gdi points</returns>
       public PointF[] Project(Vector3[] nodes)
       {
           float r = 2 * (float)Math.Tan(FOV / 2 * Math.PI / 180);
           float camDist = SceneSize / r;
           float f = ViewHalfSize/r;
           var R = Matrix4x4.CreateFromQuaternion(Orientation);

           var points = new PointF[nodes.Length];
           for (int i = 0; i < points.Length; i++)
           {
               points[i] = Project(nodes[i], f, camDist, R);
           }

           return points;
       }
       /// <summary>
       /// Uses the arc-ball calculation to find the 3D point corresponding to a
       /// particular pixel on the screen
       /// </summary>
       /// <param name="pixel">The pixel with origin on center of control.</param>
       /// <param name="arcBallFactor"></param>
       public Vector3 UnProject(Point pixel, float arcBallFactor = 1)
       {
           Ray ray = CastRayThroughPixel(pixel);
           Sphere arcBall = new Sphere(Target, arcBallFactor * SceneSize/2);
           var Rt = Matrix4x4.CreateFromQuaternion(Quaternion.Inverse(Orientation));
           bool hit = arcBall.Hit(ray, out var t);
           return Vector3.Transform(ray.GetPointAlong(t), Rt);
       }

       public bool IsVisible(Polygon polygon)
           => polygon.Nodes.Length <3 || IsVisible(polygon.Nodes[0]-Target, polygon.Normal);
       /// <summary>
       /// Determines whether a face is visible. 
       /// </summary>
       /// <param name="position">Any position on the face.</param>
       /// <param name="normal">The face normal.</param>
       public bool IsVisible(Vector3 position, Vector3 normal)
       {
           float λ = Vector3.Dot(normal, position - EyePos);

           return λ < 0;
       }

   }
   ```
3. **`Scene`** and **`VisibleObject`**. The base class for objects to be drawn is called `VisibleObject`. Everything you see in the screenshot above derives from a `VisibleObject`. This includes solids, curves and the triad of coordinates. A `Scene` is just a collection of `VisibleObject` to be drawn, and it handles the `Paint` event issued by the `Camera`. Finally it iterates through the objects and issues the command to be rendered.

   ```
   public class Scene
   {
       readonly List<VisibleObject> drawable;

       public Scene()
       {
           drawable = new List<VisibleObject>();
           Triad = new VisibleTriad("W");
       }
       [Category("Model")]
       public VisibleObject[] Drawable => drawable.ToArray();
       public T AddDrawing<T>(T drawing) where T : VisibleObject
       {
           drawable.Add(drawing);
           return drawing;
       }
       [Category("Model")]
       public VisibleTriad Triad { get; }
       public void Render(Graphics g, Camera camera)
       {
           var state = camera.SetupView(g);

           Triad.Render(g, camera, Pose.Identity);

           foreach (var item in drawable)
           {
               item.Render(g, camera, Pose.Identity);
           }
           Gdi.Style.Clear();
           g.Restore(state);

       }

   }
   ```

   and the base `VisibleObject` class

   ```
   public abstract class VisibleObject 
   {
       public abstract void Render(Graphics g, Camera camera, Pose pose);
   }
   ```

   One point to understand is that the location of each `VisibleObject` is not contained within.  This is done so multiple copies of the same object can be drawn at various locations on the screen.
4. **`Pose`** The 3D position and orientation of each object is defined with the `Pose` class, which contains a `Vector3` origin, and a `Quaternion` orientation.

   The main functionality is in the `FromLocal()` and `ToLoca()` methods that do the local to world or reverse transformations.

   ```
   public readonly struct Pose 
       : IEquatable<Pose>
   {
       readonly (Vector3 position, Quaternion orientation) data;
       public Pose(Quaternion orientation) : this(Vector3.Zero, orientation) { }
       public Pose(Vector3 position) : this(position, Quaternion.Identity) { }
       public Pose(Vector3 position, Quaternion orientation) : this()
       {
           data = (position, orientation);
       }
       public static readonly Pose Identity = new Pose(Vector3.Zero, Quaternion.Identity);
       public static implicit operator Pose(Vector3 posiiton) => new Pose(posiiton);
       public static implicit operator Pose(Quaternion rotation) => new Pose(rotation);
       public Vector3 Position { get => data.position; }
       public Quaternion Orientation { get => data.orientation; }

       public Vector3 FromLocal(Vector3 position)
           => Position +  Vector3.Transform(position, Orientation);
       public Vector3[] FromLocal(Vector3[] positions)
       {
           var R = Matrix4x4.CreateFromQuaternion(Orientation);
           Vector3[] result = new Vector3[positions.Length];
           for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
           {
               result[i] = Position + Vector3.Transform(positions[i], R);
           }
           return result;
       }
       public Vector3 FromLocalDirection(Vector3 direction)
           => Vector3.Transform(direction, Orientation);
       public Vector3[] FromLocalDirection(Vector3[] directions)
       {
           var R = Matrix4x4.CreateFromQuaternion(Orientation);
           Vector3[] result = new Vector3[directions.Length];
           for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
           {
               result[i] = Vector3.TransformNormal(directions[i], R);
           }
           return result;
       }
       public Quaternion FromLocal(Quaternion orientation)
           => Quaternion.Multiply(Orientation, orientation);
       public Pose FromLocal(Pose local) 
           => new Pose(FromLocal(local.Position), FromLocal(local.Orientation));
       public Vector3 ToLocal(Vector3 position)
           => Vector3.Transform(position-Position, Quaternion.Inverse(Orientation));
       public Vector3[] ToLocal(Vector3[] positions)
       {
           var R = Matrix4x4.CreateFromQuaternion(Quaternion.Inverse(Orientation));
           Vector3[] result = new Vector3[positions.Length];
           for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
           {
               result[i] = Vector3.Transform(positions[i]-Position, R);
           }
           return result;
       }
       public Vector3 ToLocalDirection(Vector3 direction)
           => Vector3.Transform(direction, Quaternion.Inverse(Orientation));
       public Vector3[] ToLocalDirection(Vector3[] directions)
       {
           var R = Matrix4x4.CreateFromQuaternion(Quaternion.Inverse(Orientation));
           Vector3[] result = new Vector3[directions.Length];
           for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
           {
               result[i] = Vector3.TransformNormal(directions[i], R);
           }
           return result;
       }
       public Quaternion ToLocal(Quaternion orientation)
           => Quaternion.Multiply(orientation, Quaternion.Inverse(Orientation));
       public Pose ToLocal(Pose pose)
           => new Pose(ToLocal(pose.Position), ToLocal(pose.Orientation));

       #region Algebra
       public static Pose Add(Pose A, Pose B)
       {
           return new Pose(A.data.position+B.data.position, A.data.orientation+B.data.orientation);
       }
       public static Pose Subtract(Pose A, Pose B)
       {
           return new Pose(A.data.position+B.data.position, A.data.orientation-B.data.orientation);
       }

       public static Pose Scale(float factor, Pose A)
       {
           return new Pose(factor*A.data.position, Quaternion.Multiply(A.data.orientation, factor));
       }
       #endregion

       #region Operators
       public static Pose operator +(Pose a, Pose b) => Add(a, b);
       public static Pose operator -(Pose a) => Scale(-1, a);
       public static Pose operator -(Pose a, Pose b) => Subtract(a, b);
       public static Pose operator *(float a, Pose b) => Scale(a, b);
       public static Pose operator *(Pose a, float b) => Scale(b, a);
       public static Pose operator /(Pose a, float b) => Scale(1 / b, a);
       #endregion
   }
   ```
5. **`Gdi`** is a graphics library to handle specific sub-tasks such as drawing points on the screen, drawing labels, drawing curves, and various shapes but with a specific style and handing color operations. In addition, it keeps a *current* `Pen` and `SolidFill` object for re-use defining the stroke and fill colors to be used in the low-level Gdi drawing operations. Some details are removed from below:

   ```
   public static class Gdi
   {
       /// <summary> 
       /// Converts RGB to HSL 
       /// </summary> 
       /// <remarks>Takes advantage of whats already built in to .NET by using the Color.GetHue, Color.GetSaturation and Color.GetBrightness methods</remarks> 
       /// <param name="color">A Color to convert</param> 
       /// <returns>An HSL tuple</returns> 
       public static (float H, float S, float L) GetHsl(this Color color)
       {
           var H = color.GetHue() / 360f;
           var L = color.GetBrightness();
           var S = color.GetSaturation();

           return (H, S, L);
       }
       /// <summary>
       /// Converts a color from HSL to RGB
       /// </summary>
       /// <remarks>Adapted from the algorithm in Foley and Van-Dam</remarks>
       /// <param name="hsl">The HSL tuple</param>
       /// <returns>A Color structure containing the equivalent RGB values</returns>
       public static Color GetColor(this (float H, float S, float L);
       public static Style Style { get; } = new Style();

       public static void DrawPoint(this Graphics g, Color color, PointF point, float size = 4f)
       {
           Style.Clear();
           Style.Fill.Color = color;
           g.FillEllipse(Style.Fill, point.X - size/2, point.Y - size/2, size, size);
       }
       public static void DrawLine(this Graphics g, Color color, PointF start, PointF end, float width = 1f)
       {
           Style.Stroke.Color = color;
           Style.Stroke.Width = width;
           g.DrawLine(Style.Stroke, start, end);
       }
       public static void DrawArrow(this Graphics g, Color color, PointF start, PointF end, float width = 1f);
       public static void DrawLabel(this Graphics g, Color color, PointF point, string text, ContentAlignment alignment, int offset = 2);
       public static void DrawPath(this Graphics g, GraphicsPath path, Color color, bool fill = true);

       public static void DrawCircle(this Graphics g, PointF center, float radius, Color color, bool fill = true);
       public static void DrawEllipse(this Graphics g, PointF center, float majorAxis, float minorAxis, float angle, Color color, bool fill = true);
       public static void DrawCurve(this Graphics g, PointF[] points, Color color, bool fill = true);
       public static void DrawClosedCurve(this Graphics g, PointF[] points, Color color, bool fill = true);
       public static void DrawPolygon(this Graphics g, PointF[] points, Color color, bool fill = true);
   }
   ```

   For example to draw a 3D point on the screen at location `(100,30)` with color `Red` you would issue code like this from a paint handler with access to a `Graphics g` object

   ```
   PointF point = new PointF(100,30);
   // Calls extension method `Gdi.DrawPoint()`
   g.DrawPoint(Color.Red, point, 4f);
   ```

Using the above framework to draw a single point defined by a `Vector3` from `System.Numerics` on the screen you will need the following `VisibleObject` derived class. The magic happens in the `Render()` method which uses the supplied `Camera` to project the 3D point into a pixel location. In addition, it defines a text label to draw next to the point.

```
    public class VisiblePoint : VisibleObject
    {
        public VisiblePoint(string label, Color color, float size = 4f)
        {
            Label = label;
            Color=color;
            Size=size;
        }

        public Color Color { get; }
        public float Size { get; }
        public string Label { get; }

        public override void Render(Graphics g, Camera camera, Pose pose)
        {
            var pixel = camera.Project(pose.Position);
            g.DrawPoint(Color, pixel, Size);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Label))
            {
                g.DrawLabel(Color, pixel, Label, ContentAlignment.BottomRight);
            }
        }
    }
```